# What is the maximum length for a sqoop query?

Tags: sqoop

Is there a maximum length for a sqoop query (via --query option)?

I have been able to use some pretty big queries, but am now creating a little program where queries can be passed in to the script. I have no idea how long these could be.
The queries will come from files with each line of the file ended by a \

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The maximum statement length is data base vendor-specific.  I believe SQLServer has a max somewhere over 16M characters, Informix has a 64K char limit, etc.  Also, if you're invoking from the command line the OS will limit the command length and indirectly the query length.  If you are invoking through Oozie, Oozie will impose a max length on the workflow definition (XML file) of 100K characters, although that's configurable) and that, too, will limit the length of your statement(s).